# Is it necessary to create MEX files when generating code from Simulink models?

Tags: matlab, code-generation, simulink, mex

When generating C code from a Simulink model containing normal-mode references to other models, I can see that MEX files are created in the process for those other models.

As far as I understand, these MEX files are usually created when compiling a model which references other models in accelerator mode. Therefore I don't understand the need to create them when generating C code. And even less so when generating code for a model having no accelerator-mode references.

Can someone explain why this is necessary? If not, how can I bypass the creation of those MEX files when generating code?

Comment: mex code is just "**M**atlab **EX**ecutable". Anything that can be called from MATLAB that is not MATLAB language or can be interpreted by MATLAB engine goes in a mex file. You can put C, C++ and Fortran directly, but you can also make these call any other thing in the world. MEX files are the way to generate code for MATLAB by definition, I do not understand how/why you want to bypass them

Comment: Alright a mex file is some kind of black box in which you throw anything that is not matlab code so matlab can deal with it, fine, but I still don't understand why they should be generated when generating C code that is going to be used outside of matlab...

Comment: When generating C code using Visual Studio or gcc, there are no mex files. mex files are there because you want to use the C code from MATLAB, with MATLAB inputs and/or outputs, therefore an EXE won't cut it, you need a MATLAB EXE, a MEX. Also, C code is, with your definition "anything that is not matlab code", so it must go inside this black box!

Comment: In my case, the code is generated for deployment outside of matlab so I have no use for the mex, I'd like to avoid creating them if possible.

Comment: We'd need more information, but I don't think that is possible. The most likely case, if you are doing this from MATLAB, is that some of the stuff you put in there is executed by the MATLAB engine, and if that the case, then an executable that needs MATLAB is needed. I think there is a way to deploy MATLAB code with the engine included in the executable (so it can be run in a computer that has no MATLAB), but this should not generate mex files, so if you are trying that and its generating mex files, you are doing something wrong. We can't tell what without more information.

Comment: Simulink needs to propagate data types within the model before generating code. To do this propagation, some parts of model may need to generate mex files. This could include stateflow charts,  MATLAB Function blocks or model reference blocks like you have noted. You cannot avoid this step before C code generation.

Comment: Thank you Navan . Surprisingly, I've been in touch with Mathworks support and didn't get that information...